# Transpose a dataframe column values as column headers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

A pandas dataframe has with three columns(HHID,*Name*,model).I want to bring model column values as column headers.The values in "model" should be 'Yes', if there is a model value corresponding to HHID column.

Can anyone please help me with python code for this.

Attaching the screenshot of input.

[image: Input screenshot]

Output should be:

[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: Dont link to screenshots, we [cannot copy images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Invest some time here on stackoverflow about understanding how to ask a good question, so people can give you good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
     hhid _NAME_    model
0   10006  flag4      NaN
1   10014  flag4      NaN
2   10047  flag4  make323
3   10055  flag4      NaN
4   10066  flag4  make268
5   10074  flag4      NaN
6   10085  flag4      NaN
7   10117  flag4  make146
8   10126  flag4      NaN
9   10136  flag4      NaN
10  10147  flag4  make148
```

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['model'])

     hhid _NAME_  model_make146  model_make148  model_make268  model_make323
0   10006  flag4              0              0              0              0
1   10014  flag4              0              0              0              0
2   10047  flag4              0              0              0              1
3   10055  flag4              0              0              0              0
4   10066  flag4              0              0              1              0
5   10074  flag4              0              0              0              0
6   10085  flag4              0              0              0              0
7   10117  flag4              1              0              0              0
8   10126  flag4              0              0              0              0
9   10136  flag4              0              0              0              0
10  10147  flag4              0              1              0              0
```

```
>>> # by setting prefix and prefix_sep to empty string
>>> # you could make your values as column names
>>> pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['model'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')

     hhid _NAME_  make146  make148  make268  make323
0   10006  flag4        0        0        0        0
1   10014  flag4        0        0        0        0
2   10047  flag4        0        0        0        1
3   10055  flag4        0        0        0        0
4   10066  flag4        0        0        1        0
5   10074  flag4        0        0        0        0
6   10085  flag4        0        0        0        0
7   10117  flag4        1        0        0        0
8   10126  flag4        0        0        0        0
9   10136  flag4        0        0        0        0
10  10147  flag4        0        1        0        0
```